# Podman oci .containerenv: not a directory

Tags: containers, podman

I recently swithed back to podman and got a error with my containers.

Containerfile:

```
FROM scratch

ADD ./run /

ENTRYPOINT ["/run"]
```

My applications are all static build go microservices:

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -a -tags netgo -ldflags '-w -extldflags "-static"' -o ${BINARY_NAME} *.go
```

Everything is managed from a Makefile.
Under docker everything worked great, but with podman i get this error.

```
Error: OCI runtime error: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:76: mounting "/run/containers/storage/overlay-containers/5709a135a4f1537fea1fdf8a5750534bc0f782671f115e73201569495024e4fc/userdata/.containerenv" to rootfs at "/run/.containerenv" caused: mount through procfd: open o_path procfd: open /var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/cc55a7c625e1483cc644660c8161db8a4a4a8b9c1120d132f07593834fda1a2c/merged/run/.containerenv: not a directory
```

My run command is

```
podman run -d localhost/test:1.0.0
```

OS information: Ubuntu 21.04
Kernel: 5.11.0-22-generic
Podman: 3.0.1

When i use another container like alpine, it works great under podman.

Comment: The directory _/run_ is a bit special. On my Fedora 34 it is a mount point for a tmpfs  file system. Just an idea, maybe you could try to install your application into another directory and see if the problem goes away?

Comment: run is not a directory, it is the binary application, placed at the root of the container.  open /var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/cc55a7c625e1483cc644660c8161db8a4a4a8b9c1120d132f07593834fda1a2c/merged/run/.containerenv: not a directory <- seems to be the error. But other images like the alpine, doesn't contain the directory, aswell. But the alpine does not produce the error.

Comment: Podman might expect to be able to use the path _/run_ for other things. See for instance https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/895b8151889422aac1f9b72eebe6d62e8e15095c/libpod/container_internal_linux.go#L1578   and https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/895b8151889422aac1f9b72eebe6d62e8e15095c/libpod/container_internal_linux.go#L1623

Answer (score 3):

Just to be sure, do not name the executables, like standard linux directories.

Thanks to Erik Sjölund